# Xamarin iOS equivalent to System.loadLibrary

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

In an Android app I've added a c++ file (native-lib.cpp) that has a few methods which return some data.

For example:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_my_android_namespace_activities_activity_name_getX(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                       jobject instance) {

    return env->NewStringUTF("some bla bla");
}
```

Then in the Java code I could use:

```
System.loadLibrary("native-lib");

public native String getX();
```

How can I achieve the same in an iOS app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Xamarin.iOS` has the `ObjCRuntime` namespace that includes a number of std. ObjC wrappers:

```
IntPtr h = Dlfcn.dlopen ("libMySpecialSauceLibrary.dylib", 0);
if (h == IntPtr.Zero) {
     // Failed load
} else {
    // Successful load
    Dlfcn.dlclose (h);
}
```

These are just wrappers via C#'s `DllImport` so look at the ObjC docs for parameter docs, setup, library locations, etc.. i.e.

```
[DllImport ("libSystem.dylib")]
public static extern IntPtr dlopen (string path, int mode);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!